# Ring theory question- boole?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $(A,+,*)$ a ring which is not a field such that for any noninvertible $x,x^2=x$. The problem asks to prove that:
1) a+x is noninvertible for all $x-$noninvertible and nonzero and $a$ invertible.
2)$a^2=a$,for all a in A.

I proved that A has only one unit, which makes me think that I have an error in my proof.
1) $ax$ and $1+ax$ are non invertible,etc
Let x noninvertible,a invertible
2)$(a+x)^2=a^2+x+ ax+xa=a+x => a^2+ax+xa=a $ Divide by $a^2$ and replace $a^-1=a$. As we do it for all a invertible, we have $ax+xa=a-1$
Replacing this in the intial equation, we obtain: $(a+x)^2=a^2+x^2+ax+xa=a^2+a-1+x=a= x=> a^2=1$. This means that A in commutative so ax=xa.
It is easy to see that $x+x=0$ so in particular $ax+ax=0$  so $a^2=a$(from the initial equation), so $a=1.$ SO we have only one invertible element, which is exactly 1.
Does this seem correct? thanks

Comment: A Boolean ring only has one invertible element, so your intuition about that being a problem is wrong. Isn't it obviously false that the sum of an invertible and a noninvertible is non invertible? Like $1+0$, for example?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention for all x nonzero. thank you